# Infinite intersection of open sets (again): Understanding the counter example

Tags: real-analysis

I know there are many questions on this topic already. Hence the title. Unfortunately, amongst the many questions posted, I couldn't find answers that directly addressed my question. If someone finds or knows of a relevant link, that would be excellent too. Ok, here goes:

The quintessential counter example to closure of open sets under infinite intersections is $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1/n,1/n)$. Heuristically, this is clearly 0. However, I don't rigorously understand why this is 0.

I understand the epsilon delta def of limit (as well as someone talking UG analysis is expected to know it). However, I don't understand why we can apply the limit here without justification. Furthermore, since 1/n only approaches zero without ever reaching it, wouldn't it make sense that the intersection remain open.

The more I think about this question the more silly it feels (i.e. "Of course lim(1/n)=0"). However, I can't alleviate this itch in the back of my brain telling me that I am missing something or something is being handwaved. Any assistance alleviating that itch (by scratching it or telling me it's all in my head lol) would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you agree that for any nonzero real number $x$ there is an integer $n$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{n} < |x|$?

Comment: First, that's not a limit, and the language of limits, like epsilons and deltas, really doesn't apply here. Second, that intersection isn't $0$, it's $\{0\}$, the set containing only the number $0$. And thirdly, can you name any number that's not zero that's contained in all of those sets?

Comment: @HansLundmark 100% I would agree

Comment: @EricH: OK. Then the number $x$ doesn't belong to the interval $(-\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{1}{n})$ for that particular $n$, right? Which means that $x$ can't belong to the intersection of *all* such intervals either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, one cannot apply a limit here without justification, and I would go so far as to suggest that it muddies the water a bit.

Formally and rigorously, we note that

$$x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} S_i \iff (\forall i \in I)(x \in S_i)$$

and

$$A = B \iff (A \subseteq B \land B \subseteq A)$$

Hence, to find out what $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n,1/n)$ consists of, we first note the obvious: that $0 \in (-1/n,1/n)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This tells us that $\{0\} \subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n,1/n)$.

I claim $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n,1/n) \subseteq \{0\}$, and argue by contradiction. Take $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n,1/n)$ with $x \ne 0$. Clearly, we must have $x \in (-1,1) \setminus \{0\}$ (it must lie in every set, and hence in the first set). If $x \in (0,1)$, one knows that $1/n < x$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

> **Why?** This can be argued through limits, if one is careful. The function $f(n) := 1/n$ on $(0,\infty)$ is decreasing, and has $0$ as a lower bound, trivially. One can in fact show that $\inf f(n) = 0$. Hence, $\lim f(n) = 0$. But then $1/n < x$ eventually. Otherwise, this means that $1/n$ is bounded away from $0$ by $x$, but this would prevent the convergence of the limit.
>
> However, one need not overcomplicate matters by appealing to, ultimately, $\varepsilon$-$\delta$, and just use a common property that precedes even that in one's study of analysis: [the Archimedean principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property), which pretty much states the desired result as-is. A proof is [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle).

Let $N$ be the first natural number such that $1/N < x$. Then $x \not \in (-1/N,1/N)$ and hence not in the intersection. The argument for when $x \in (-1,0)$ is analogous.

In both cases, we see that assuming that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n,1/n)$ contains elements other than zero results in a contradiction. Hence, it must contain only $0$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the question seriously! I'd give you (+1) if I could. It still seems very strange the intersection is {0}. However, your proof does make total sense, so it must be so! On an unrelated note, since you mentioned Archimedean principle, do all proofs of convergence (for limits of sequences) use Archimedean Principle (at least indirectly)? I have yet to see one that doesn't in some way reduce to 0< *Insert relevant $|s_n-s|$* <1/N <$\epsilon$

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say *all* (because that is a very strong statement), but many proofs do make use of it on some level.